# WPF user control inside DataGrid doesn't rise CellEditEnding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I have some problems with a datagrid which selection's unit is set to **Cell**. I wanted to overwrite the **datagridcell** template by adding a custom user control inside of it, by doing this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
            <UserControls:ByteBox x:Name="ByteBoxControl" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ByteValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>                
</Style>
```

Inside the UserControl the ByteValue is a TextBox Binding. When I edit the textbox, it doesn't call the **CellEditChanged** like it does if I don't overwrite the DataGridCell Template.

So the behavior I need is to have CellEditChanged event raised when the textbox inside the UserControl is updated.

Comment: I have to specify that even If I only add a textbox inside the control template instead of a usercontrol the behavior is the same.